# How to center images on bootstrap 4 card when displayed on phone?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have bootstrap 4 grid having two equal columns each column having a card which has two images displayed on top of card side by side on desktop. On smaller devices grid becomes single column (col-lg-6 col-sm-12) in which case if device width is too small the two images automatically stack on top of each other. The issue is that when they stack on top of each other, the images are aligned to left but I want them centered in this scenario. How to do that?

Another option that can be even better is to auto scale image to take full width of card in case they are stacked on top of each in the card for small devices. How to do this approach? I tried img-fluid class on img element but does not work.

Here is the code:

```
    <div class="container">

  <!--Grid row-->
    <div class="row">

     <!--Grid column-->
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 ">

    <!--Card-->
    <div class="card mb-4">  
    <!--Card image-->
        <div class="">
    <span class="">
      <img src="DSC_0043.JPG" alt="" class=" rounded mb-1 img-fluid">
    </span>
    <span class="">
      <img src="DSC_0042.JPG" alt="" class=" rounded mb-1 img-fluid">
    </span>
    </div> 
    <!--/ Card image-->

    <!--Card content-->
      <div class="card-body">
        <!--Title-->
        <h5 class="card-title">Lorum Ipsum</h5>
    <div class="card-text">
      <div>HLorum Ipsum .. lorum ipsum </div>

    </div>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">View More Details</a>

    </div>

    <div class="card-footer">
<span class="" >Lorum ipsum </span> 
    </div>



    </div>
  <!--/.Card-->

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 d-flex22">

      <!--Card-->
    <div class="card mb-4">  
    <!--Card image-->
        <div class="">
    <span class="">
      <img src="DSC_0043.JPG" alt="" class=" rounded mb-1 img-fluid">
    </span>
    <span class="">
      <img src="DSC_0042.JPG" alt="" class=" rounded mb-1 img-fluid">
    </span>
    </div> 
    <!--/ Card image-->

    <!--Card content-->
      <div class="card-body">
        <!--Title-->
        <h5 class="card-title">Lorum Ipsum</h5>
    <div class="card-text">
      <div>HLorum Ipsum .. lorum ipsum </div>

    </div>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">View More Details</a>

    </div>

    <div class="card-footer">
<span class="" >Lorum ipsum </span> 
    </div>



    </div>
  <!--/.Card-->

  </div>
  <!--/ Grid column-->

  </div>
    <!--/Grid row-->

</div>
```

Comment: Post the code in the question

Comment: Given that you have both images wrapped in a parent `div` why not apply `text-center` to that wrapper?

Comment: Robert that works! next thing I am looking for auto scale images if they are stacked upon each other without disturbing desktop layout.